# wxPython Drag and Drop exit code 139 crash

Tags: wxpython

I am experimenting with wxPython trying to learn drag and drop. Why doesn't the following work on Linux? The app starts up, but when I drag the static text into the text field, I get a 139 exit code with version 2.8 using python 2.7.

```
import wx
class DropTarget(wx.DropTarget):
    def __init__(self):
            wx.DropTarget.__init__(self)
            self.dataobject = wx.PyTextDataObject()
            self.SetDataObject(self.dataobject)
    def OnData(self, x, y, d):
            pass

class Txt(wx.StaticText):
    def __init__(self, parent, label_):
            wx.StaticText.__init__(self, parent, label=label_)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.handle)
    def handle(self, event):
            ds = wx.DropSource(self)
            d = wx.PyTextDataObject('some text')
            ds.SetData(d)
            ds.DoDragDrop(True)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'whatevs')
            main_panel = wx.Panel(self)

            txt = Txt(main_panel, 'ONE')
            txt2 = wx.TextCtrl(main_panel)

            s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            s.Add(txt)
            s.Add(txt2)
            main_panel.SetSizer(s)

            dt = DropTarget()
            txt2.SetDropTarget(dt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame().Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the line

```
        ds = wx.DropSource(self)
```

with

```
        ds = wx.DropSource(self.GetParent())
```

I was able to reproduce the crash you are seeing, but once I made the above change the crash went away.

It seems that for some reason, wx doesn't like instances of `wx.StaticText` (or subclasses of it in your case) being passed to the `wx.DropSource` constructor.  I'm not sure why.

I changed your code so that `Txt` derived from `wx.TextCtrl` instead of `wx.StaticText` and I couldn't reproduce the problem any more.  I also tried playing around with the first sample program found on http://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop, and found that I could make it crash if I set the drop source to be one of the `StaticText` objects this code creates instead of a `TextCtrl`.

If there's anything in the wxWidgets or wxPython documentation that says you can't use a `wx.StaticText` as a drop source, I didn't find it.  It certainly wasn't obvious to me.  (The [documentation for wxDropSource](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_drop_source.html) says that you pass to each constructor

> The window which initiates the drag and drop operation.

However, there doesn't appear to be any restriction on the types of 'window' (or 'widget') that you can use as a drop source.)